# Foreach Loop not displaying spaces between items in @Html.DisplayFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have seen a few similar questions on here and have tried them but the solutions didn't seem to work for my problem.

As you can see in my view I have a `@Html.DisplayFor` within a `Foreach` loop, this display shows all the GroupID's within a certain section, but instead of displaying "1 2 3 4 5" it will display "12345".

The Second row in the table (`@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Group)`) is where there is the problem (row has expand/collapse capability).

**View**

```
<table>
     <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-1">+</td>
                <td class="col-md-2">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-1" colspan="3"><p style="display:none">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Group)</p></td>
            </tr>
        }
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Below I have made a simple JSFiddle so it is easier to visualise what it is that I am talking about. Thanks in advance for your help and if you need any more info please ask.
**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjardine/vu32c6bh/)**

**EDIT**
I have added the controller below to show what Group is.

```
public ActionResult SectionTable()
        {
            Manager manager = new Manager();
            var data3 = manager.GetAllSections();
            var groups = manager.GetAllGroups();
            var sectionDetails = from u in data3

                               select new SectionDetail
                               {
                                   SectionID = u.Id,
                                   Name = u.Name,
                                   Description = u.Description,
                                   Group = (from g in groups
                                           where g.SectionId == u.Id
                                           select new GroupDetail() { GroupID = g.Id, GroupDescription = g.Description, GroupName = g.Name, GroupSectionID = g.SectionId, Rights = g.Rights, RightsID = g.RightsId, SectionName = g.SectionName }).ToList()


                               };
            return View(sectionDetails.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Unsure what your question is. What is typeof `Group`? - your only outputting one property per row so you will only get one value per row (not 5) - is typeof `Group` a collection?

Comment: Group is a List of all the Groups in the section, the question is how to i make it so there is a space between each List item

Comment: can show the code where you are populating the model.

Comment: Then you will need to use a nested foreach loop and render each group in  a `<span>` (and depending on how much spacing you want, you could style the span elements as `inline-block` and add margins or padding)

Comment: Could you post an example please? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Have done :) @psylogic

Comment: @hjardine have done what??

Comment: "can show the code where you are populating the model" @psylogic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second row, you need to include a nested `foreach` block and render each `Group` inside a `<span>` element, for example

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">+</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1" colspan="3">
          @foreach(var group in item.Group)
          {
            <span class="group">@group.GroupID</span> // add class name if you want additional spacing
          }
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then depending on how much spacing you want, your could use .css

```
.group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0, 10px;
}
```

Side note: Since property `Group` is a collection, I recommend you use conventional naming practices and rename you property to `Groups` (plural)

Comment: This returned: 12345 12345 12345 12345 @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then you need to show your models are the data they contain. Looking back at your previous answers its almost impossible to understand what your actually doing - in one question you had 3 properties of type `GroupDetail` then in the last question you had only one, now it seems to be a collection (and if its still typeof `GroupDetail` then you should be rendering a property of it - for example `Group.GroupID`)

Comment: I guess the problem is that they are all coming through as one chunk of data, but when debugging and I look at the Group section it is Type "System.Collections.Generic.List<Application.Models.GroupDetail>" and has a "Count = x", when opening this, it shows [0], [1], [2].... and when opening these it has GroupDescription, GroupID etc... So it must recognise that they are separate?

Comment: But it wont allow me to do `item.Group.GroupID` for example, it only allows me to do `item.Group`

Comment: Also there is only one GroupDetail property in SectionDetail called Group

Comment: Of course it will (unless you have other problems) `Group` is a collection of `GroupDetail` (FGS, rename it to Groups) and `GroupDetail` contains a property `GroupID`. But in any case its `@foreach(var group in item.Group) { @group.GroupID }` (`not item.Group.GroupID`)

Comment: Impossible - You have a query where you set `Group = (from g in groups ......).ToList()` which means its a collection NOT a single object.